# How to abbreviate journal name with the first letters？

Tags: beamer, bibentry

I use the command "bibentry" to show the references in the slides with beamer.
And i want to get an abbreviated journal name, e.g. "Physical Review Letters" thansfors into "PRL". How can I achieve that? How to modify the "bst" file?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think it is better to modify the bib file to use the abbreviations (carefully, not to break things; it would be a slightly different question). The reason is that many journals have standard abbreviations, but they are **not** the first letters, see e.g. _ApJ_ for _Astrophysical Journal_.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i do not want to modify the bib file. Whether there is some way to create a list for the abbreviations?

Comment: I would suggest you create two entries -- one with the full name of the journal in the `journal` field, the other with the abbreviated name. You'd then modify argument of the `\cite` command to point to one or the other entry.

Comment: That's an interesting question; whether you can define a list of abbreviations of the  journals and map it.

Comment: @Mico That's not a systematic solution, as I realize. I like the idea of a list of journal abbreviations, and with Biblatex + expl3, nothing is impossible, right? :)

Comment: @yo' - Sorry, I haven't mastered biblatex -- or expl3 -- yet. As you may have noticed from some of the answers I've posted, I'm more into Lua(La)TeX...

Comment: @GuangX Have you considered putting only a command like `\prl` in your `.bib` file and define these in your beamer document, e.g. `\newcommand\prl{PRL}`? This has the advantage, that when you want to reuse your `.bib` file for let's say an article, you can simply change the command there to `\newcommand\prl{Phys.~Rev.~Lett.}` or whatever.